# Serilog doesn't log into DB when ASP.NET MVC app hosted

Tags: asp.net-mvc, logging, serilog

Please help me with Serilog logger. I have a problem with logging into database:

- when my app is running on localhost -> logger logs into **local** db
- when my app is running on localhost -> logger logs into **hosted** DB
- when my app is hosted on the domain -> logger doesn't log in the hosted db

All the time I'm using the same connection string.
Here is my configuration of the logger. My tests were reated to WriteTestInformation method. This static class is placed in the Common project in the solution. I'm using logger in ASP.NET MVC app, and in the service layer.

```
public static class Serilogger
{
    private static readonly ILogger Informationlog;
    private static readonly string _connectionString;

    static Serilogger()
    {
        _connectionString = @"Server=xyz,2401; Database=xyz;User Id=xyz_Serilog;Password=***;...";

        Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(Console.Error);
        var sinkOpts = new MSSqlServerSinkOptions();
        sinkOpts.TableName = "Logs";

        Informationlog = new LoggerConfiguration()
             .MinimumLevel.Information()
            .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(
                connectionString: _connectionString,
                sinkOptions: sinkOpts)
            .CreateLogger();
    }

    public static void WriteTestInformation(string prop1, string prop2)
    {
        Informationlog.Write(LogEventLevel.Information, "Test: {prop1} {prop2}", prop1, prop2);
    }
}
```

I wil be grateful for your help,
Regards

Comment: In your description you listed two different behaviors for "when my app is running on localhost", could you clarify what the difference is? Also could you be more descriptive of the error or wrong behavior you're getting? You said that it doesn't log to the db, but what does it do?

Comment: When I run this app in the debug mode on my local machine - it logs into the db. I have only one place when I log for tests and after reaching this part of code as a user, there are new records in the sql table. But when I publish the app and do the same test - there are no new logs in this table. Seems like the hosted app can not insert into it but I am sure it can do that (users can make comments etc..)

Comment: Hard to say about the behavior... I don't know what can I do to see the behavior of the serilog during this process. I see only the result - no new logs when logger should insert new records into the table

Comment: he difference between two local cases is the DB. In the first case I have DB in my local sql server, in the second one hosted DB on my provider's server. The db users and permissions, roles for them are the same

Comment: Unfortunately it's going to be very difficult if not impossible for someone to tell you what is going wrong. In all likelihood there is something wrong with your network configuration or similar IT type issues. I'm not personally familiar with serilog, so maybe what you're seeing is a common issue that someone will recognize, but I kind of doubt it. Good luck